# Submit html form without refresh or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am making a webpage that has a html form in it and some php code to process the form data. What I want to do is make it so it doesnt refresh the page after each button press and save the data to a file? How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form method="post" action="out.php">

            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="A" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="B" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="C" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="D" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="E" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="F" />
            <input type="submit" name="foo" value="G" />

        </form>

        <?php
        $name = $_POST['foo'];
        $fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "w");
        fwrite($fp, "");
        $savestring = $name;
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);
        fclose($fp);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @saty: Reading is helpful sometimes :-)

Comment: just use ajax! and change input tag to button(html5)

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery you can still fall back to plain java AJAX-Calls.

Comment: bind an event to those `input[type=submit]` so that it wont submit the form. then use ajax to proccess the data you want..

Comment: OMG that's the worst form I have ever seen in my life :O SOrry for commenting :p

Comment: Your PHP form-handling logic should happen before any HTML begins.

Comment: how is this the worst form ever? its just buttons?

Comment: @jacoby  .. Really? How many input type submit does a form have lol ? :p

Comment: You are too young to understand

Comment: Yeah really so. I will have to be reborn to understand that gibberish lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're avoiding JavaScript altogether, you can target a hidden iframe.

CSS:

```
iframe.hidden{ display:none }
```

HTML:

```
<iframe name="iframe" width="0" height="0" tabindex="-1" class="hidden"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="out.php" target="iframe">...
```

However, you're better off using JavaScript to ensure the data has submitted properly. What if the user's session has expired? What if their internet connection is unstable? How will they know the data validated OK?

Answer (score 1):

> User Jquery Called for that purposed simple 
>   download any  jquery-1.11.3.js up or down version

```
        <form method="post" action="">

        <input type="submit" id='fooA' name="foo" value="A" />
        <input type="submit" id= 'fooB' name="foo" value="B" />

    </form>


   <script>
    $('#fooA').click(function(){

     var fooA  =  this.val();

         $.ajax({
           type : 'post',
           url  : 'out.php',
           data : {'fooA':fooA},
           success: function(data){

           }
        });
  });
   </script>
```

> get foo value in out.php

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST['fooA'];
    $fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, "");
    $savestring = $name;
    fwrite($fp, $savestring);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

> in data you must be send name of variable and then get in php file ...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you must use some kind of javascript ajax call. PHP works server side and therefore php code only gets processed on the server. That's where javascript comes in. Javascirpt runs on the clients browser. If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use plain javascript ajax i.e. xmlhttprequests, but then you have to worry about various browser support and all that fun stuff.

If you use a third party javascript library, e.g. jQuery, that takes care of all the boring things, such as browser support. When doing ajax, I would highly recommend using some sort of third party library, jQuery being probably the most popular one.

Comment: "To achieve this you must use some kind of javascript ajax call." This is not true, see my answer.

Comment: @rybo111 My bad, you're right, that's a pretty neat way of doing it without javascript